# How to Launch Google Map Intent with My Current Location

Tags: android

Im a newbie here in android programming.
Here is my simple code just to launch the intent with the given coordinates. The problem is, how to get my current location and use it to show my current location whenever the google map intent starts.

```
public void viewroute (View view)
{
    if  (view.getId()==R.id.ViewRoute)
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:9.8500,124.1435"));
        startActivity(intent);
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is the problem you are having?
Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help!

Comment: hello @FluffyKitten my problem is i want to launch an google map intent with my current location, in my example it shows a sample coordinates. What i want is my current coordinates/location.

Comment: You should update your answer with any additional information, as people can miss ir if its in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to try like this

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

for more information visit here  : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

if you need with direction follow this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it will help you :)