# Address link to open Google maps APP on Android Device

Tags: android, html, google-maps

I have a webpage for my driver that has client name, pick up address, drop off address.
We are using Appypie as wrapper which uses android browser, anyway issue is when I try to make address clickable to open navigation, it trying to open it inside appypie as an webpage instead of opening Google maps Apk, is there anyway you guys can help me out with this.
Any html code that will do what I need.

Comment: i guess ill try to ask another way, how can i invoke google maps(navigation) app to open by clicking on address in web browser? as of now it opens google maps in browser with <a href

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to Maps URLs? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide Also check out Android intents https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: i've tried that but still can't open it it keeps opening in browser and when i click open app all i get is google play store screen with google services page not sure why.

Comment: i've tried to do it with waze, what happens it loads navigation in waze and when i click open in app it gives me option to load with browsers only, not showing me google maps app or waze.. not sure what's going on

Comment: <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv"><a class="dxeHyperlink_Moderno1" href="https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17" style="font-size:Larger;">270 Norhland Blvd 45246</a></td>    <example of code for waze>

Comment: Do you have the Google maps app installed on your android device?

Comment: yes actually this is what i found on this website but it doesn't give me start point or destination just opens app

Comment: i've been trying to use different options and still failing...<a href="intent://maps.google.com/geo:0.0&amp;api=1&amp;destination=39.20701,-84.3774;/#Intent;scheme=geo;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end;" >5150 E Galbraith Rd 45236      all it does just opens google maps main screen tried different options but still getting same result.. anyone have an idea how to include destination and have start point as current location?

Comment: one more step forward) thanks to stackoverflow found and fixed most of the code still can't figure out one part how to set current location by default here is code that works without using current location `code`<a href="intent://maps.google.com/geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway%2C+CAS;/#Intent;scheme=geo;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end;">Navigate To Test Address</a>`code`

Comment: The following related threads may hopefully help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310436/open-map-to-show-direction-from-current-location-through-intent-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378688/how-to-launch-google-map-intent-with-my-current-location